# Clickable bubble control auto slideshow pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How could I link the marked bubble to JavaScript auto slider (window.setInterval(function slideA() { ) ? Check codes to understand this issue. The slides go automatically, but the bubble only react on clicks.

```js
var imagecount = 1;
var total = 3;

function slide(x) {
 var Image = document.getElementById('img');
 var nodes = document.getElementById('bubbles').getElementsByTagName('div');
        for(var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
        if(i == imagecount-1) {
        nodes[i].style.backgroundColor = '#F86215';
        }
        else {
        nodes[i].style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';    
          }
            }      
 imagecount = imagecount + x;
 if (imagecount > total){ imagecount = 1;}
 if (imagecount < 1){ imagecount = total;}
 Image.src = "IMAGE/img"+ imagecount +".jpg";
 }
 
window.setInterval(function slideA() {
 var Image = document.getElementById('img'); 
 imagecount = imagecount + 1;
 if (imagecount > total){ imagecount = 1;}
 if (imagecount < 1){ imagecount = total;}
 Image.src = "IMAGE/img"+ imagecount +".jpg";
 }, 5000);
 
function selectSlide(slideNumber){
    imagecount = slideNumber;
    var Image = document.getElementById('img');
    Image.src = "IMAGE/img"+imagecount +".jpg";
} 

function selectSlide(slideNumber, divid){
   var nodes = document.getElementById('bubbles').getElementsByTagName('div');
     for(var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
            nodes[i].style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
        }        
  divid.style.backgroundColor = '#F86215';
    imagecount = slideNumber;
    var Image = document.getElementById('img');
    Image.src = "IMAGE/img"+imagecount +".jpg";
  
  }
```

```css
#img {
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 height: auto;
}
.container-fluid {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 position: relative;
}

.container-fluid #left-arrow .left {
 width: 60px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 31%;
 left: 0px;
}
.container-fluid #right-arrow .right {
 position: absolute;
 top: 31%;
 right: 0px;
 width: 60px;
}

.container #left-arrow .left:hover {
 cursor:pointer;
 cursor: hand;
}
.container #right-arrow .right:hover {
 cursor:pointer;
 cursor: hand;
}

#bubbles{
 width: 120px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 text-align: center;
 top: 80%;
 position: absolute;
 left: 45%;
} 

#bubbles > div{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 margin: 24px 10px 0px 10px;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
 text-align: center;
 border: 2px solid #F86215;
 border-radius: 100%;
 font-size: 19px;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: background 0.3s linear 0s;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
<img src="IMAGE/img1.jpg" alt="" id="img"/>
<div id="left-arrow"><img onClick="slide(-1)" class="left" src="IMAGE/arrow-left.png" alt=""/></div>
<div id="right-arrow"><img onClick="slide(1)" class="right" src="IMAGE/arrow-right.png" alt=""/></div>

<div id="bubbles"> 
<div onclick="selectSlide(1,this)" style="background:#F86215;"></div> 
<div onclick="selectSlide(2,this)"></div> 
<div onclick="selectSlide(3,this)"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `total` and `imagecount` are not defined, you're gonna need to add a little more code here, or create a JSFiddle.

Comment: Hopefully it works well now

Comment: I can't test this, you don't have code that catches the clicks on the bubbles.

Comment: I have now add all my codes. Sorry forgot to add that JavaScript part which reacts to mouseclicks.

Answer (score 0):

Took a while to get a JS only answer working, but here it is!

Updated HTML

```
<div id="bubbles">
    <div class="bubble" onclick="selectSlide(1,this)" style="background:#F86215;"></div>
    <div class="bubble" onclick="selectSlide(2,this)"></div>
    <div class="bubble" onclick="selectSlide(3,this)"></div>
</div>
```

Updated Javascript

```
window.setInterval(function slideA() {
    var image = document.getElementById('img');
    imagecount = imagecount + 1;
    if (imagecount > total) {
      imagecount = 1;
    }
    if (imagecount < 1) {
      imagecount = total;
    }
    image.src = "IMAGE/img" + imagecount + ".jpg";
    var bubbles = document.getElementsByClassName("bubble");
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < bubbles.length; i++) {
      bubbles[i].style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
    }
    document.getElementsByClassName("bubble")[imagecount - 1].style.backgroundColor = '#F86215';
  }, 5000);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ArcaneCraeda/2pf8v0nc/9/)